# GWT, PhoneGap and Video VLC

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, cordova, vlc

I would like to build a GWT-Phonegap app that can be ran:

- In a normal web browser or mobile browser
- On an Android phone/tablet device
- On an iPhone/iPad device
- On a Windows phone/tablet device

So GWT compiles my Java sources into JavaScript (which get executed directly by web and mobile browsers), and then GWT-Phonegap binds that JavaScript to a native binary for Android, iOS and Windows devices.

Here's the kicker: I want to embed a VLC media player into the app. So no matter what platform you're accessing my app from (web, mobile or native), you will be able to watch video through the embedded VLC player.

According to [this page from VLC's site](http://wiki.videolan.org/GWT), this is easy enough to do for web/mobile platforms. But what about native platforms? Is this even possible? What would my possible solutions be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use vlc, you will have to write a native phonegap plugin and then cal it from gwt via jsni.

In the link you send you call the vlc viewer through a plugin installed in FF or activex control for IE. They dont say anything about webkit.

Vlc can be compiled in android and ios, so in theory you can create that pluging, think that a phonegap plugin has a native part for each platform, here you take the code from vlc sources, and a js part which could be shared for all platforms.

Another option which works fine is to use the [phonegap-video](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) plugin to play videos in android and standard html video tag for ios.

Comment: Hey! Nice call with the `phonegap-video` plugin @Manolo (+1). Thanks!

Comment: With the phonegap-video plugin i guess you have only html5-players. so it won't work on lagecy-browser (like IE7, etc.) on desktop. there you still have to implement the vlc-player with jsni.